# Error propogation with Spray Route Concatenation

Tags: java, scala, spray

Facing a slight issue. I've extracted the issue out with some example code, so forgive the crudeness!

I have a series of routes in Spray. I also have some custom directives too to encapsulate logic.

```
countrySegment {
    ???
} ~ pathPrefix("England") {
    ???
}  ~ pathPrefix("America") {
    pathPrefix("Texas") {
        pathEnd {
            ???
        }
    }
}
```

The country segment method looks like so:

```
def countrySegment(route: Activity => Route): Route = {
    println("in country segment")
    pathPrefix(Segment) { segment =>
        Country(segment) match {
            case Some(country) => route(country)
            case None => reject(SegmentRejection("contry"))
        }
    }
}
```

The simple intention to be to throw a rejection if the path prefix doesn't pass my pattern match.

When attempting to post json to a route and marshal it in a case class `entity(as[CountryInformation])` this will happen, unless the request is malformed. Instead of throwing an error here, it actually bubbles upto countrySegment and throws an unrelated error there.

Looking at the documentation for Route Concatentation or `~` this appears to be desired behaviour,

"Returns a Route that chains two Routes. If the first Route rejects the request the second route is given a chance to act upon the request."

If I remove the countySegment block the error is handled at the right point.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Am I using route concatenation correctly? Why might this error be bubbling up?

Thanks all,

Again I've tried to simplify the issue, but please let me know if you'd like to see real code or just some more information.